# Touch and Drag Issues Unity 2D Game

Tags: android, touch, 2d, unity-game-engine

I am having a few issues with my touch controls.

1) My game is 2D. When I tested this on my android device the 2D image will almost disappear when shifting from right touch to left touch. The object is being treated as 3D object. I think this has something to do with the Z space.

2) How could I make the character move like in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hckY75j_lg. In this case any place you touch the screen grabs the player (head) and moves exactly exactly as the finger does.

Any help would appreciated!

Here's my code:

public class TouchLogic : MonoBehaviour {

```
 public static int currTouch = 0;
 private Ray ray;
 private RaycastHit rayHitInfo = new RaycastHit ();
 [HideInInspector ]
 public int touch2Watch=64;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     if (Input.touches.Length <= 0) {
     } else {
         for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {
             currTouch = i;
             if (this.GetComponent <GUITexture >() != null && (this.GetComponent <GUITexture >().HitTest (Input.GetTouch (i).position))) {
                 if (Input.GetTouch (i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                     this.SendMessage ("OnTouchBegan");
                 }
                 if (Input.GetTouch (i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended ) {
                     this.SendMessage ("OnTouchEnded");
                 }    
                 if (Input.GetTouch (i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved ) {
                     this.SendMessage ("OnTouchMoved");
                 }
             }
             ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.GetTouch (i).position);
             switch (Input.GetTouch (i).phase) {
             case TouchPhase .Began:
                 this.SendMessage ("OnTouchBeganAnywhere");
                 if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out rayHitInfo))
                     rayHitInfo.transform.gameObject.SendMessage ("OnTouchBegan2D");
                 break;
             case TouchPhase .Ended :
                 this.SendMessage ("OnTouchEndedAnywhere");
                 if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out rayHitInfo))
                     rayHitInfo.transform.gameObject.SendMessage ("OnTouchEnded2D");
                 break;
             case TouchPhase .Moved :
                 this.SendMessage ("OnTouchMovedAnywhere");
                 if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out rayHitInfo))
                     rayHitInfo.transform.gameObject.SendMessage ("OnTouchMoved2D");
                 break;
             case TouchPhase .Stationary :
                 this.SendMessage ("OnTouchStayedAnywhere");
                 if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out rayHitInfo))
                     rayHitInfo.transform.gameObject.SendMessage ("OnTouchStayed2D");
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

}

public class FollowTouch : TouchLogic {

```
 public float speed=1f;
 private Vector3 finger;
 private Transform myTrans, camTrans;
 void Start () {
     myTrans = this.transform;
     camTrans = Camera.main.transform;
 }
 void LookAtFinger(){
     Vector3 tempTouch=new Vector3 (Input.GetTouch (touch2Watch ).position .x,Input.GetTouch (touch2Watch ).position .y,
         camTrans .position.y-myTrans .position .y);
     finger = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (tempTouch);
     myTrans.LookAt (finger);
     myTrans.Translate (Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
 }
 void OnTouchMovedAnywhere(){
     LookAtFinger ();
 }
 void OnTouchStayedAnywhere(){
     LookAtFinger ();
 }
 void OnTouchBeganAnywhere(){
     touch2Watch = TouchLogic.currTouch;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making 2d game you have to use

```
Vector3.up
```

instead of

```
Vector3.forward
```